# Vectors inside a struct in C++

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct node {
  char name_;
  vector<node*> nbs_;
};

node a, b, c;
  a.name_ = 'a';
  b.name_ = 'b';
  c.name_ = 'c';
  a.nbs_.push_back(&b);
  a.nbs_.push_back(&c);

  for (vector<node*>::iterator i = a.nbs_.begin(); i != a.nbs_.begin(); i++) {
    cout << (*i)->name_;
  }
```

Why isn't the above code working. It prints nothing. I wanted it to print node b's and c's name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
i != a.nbs_.begin();
```

should be

```
i != a.nbs_.end();
```